# Wordpress - Can't add_option do database upon register_activation_hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin on my localhost using MAMP.

In my main plugin file, I have these lines in the beginning:

```
define ('MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

// Include admin.php if admin user
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require_once( MY_PLUGIN_PATH .  'admin/admin.php');
}
```

In my admin.php I have these lines for setting up database upon activation:

```
// Runs when plugin is activated
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'clsc_install');
// Create new database fields
function clsc_install() {
    $clsc_options = array(

        'Login_link'        => 'test1',
        'Login_string'      => 'test2',
        'Login_class'       => 'test3',
        'Logout_link'       => 'test4',
        'Logout_string'     => 'test5',
        'Logout_class'      => 'test6',
        'Account_link'      => 'test7',
        'Account_string'    => 'test8',
        'Account_class'     => 'test9'

    );
    add_option('clsc_options', $clsc_options, '', 'yes');
}
```

I don't see any options made to the database upon plugin activation.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing wrong with

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'clsc_install');
```

The first parameter of `register_activation_hook` should be  **main plugin file** and On `admin.php` file `__FILE__` refer to `admin.php` not main plugin file.

Either you can put `register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'clsc_install');` into main plugin file OR refer first parameter to the `main plugin file`.

main_plugin_file.php

```
#main_plugin_file.php
define ('MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

// Include admin.php if admin user
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require_once( MY_PLUGIN_PATH .  'admin/admin.php');
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'clsc_install');
```

OR

declare `main plugin file path` to a constant or variable and refer it to `register_activation_hook` first parameter.

plugin_main_file.php

```
define ('MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));
define ('PLUGIN_MAIN_FILE',__FILE__);

// Include admin.php if admin user
if ( is_admin() ) {
    require_once( MY_PLUGIN_PATH .  'admin/admin.php');
}
```

admin.php

```
// Runs when plugin is activated
register_activation_hook(PLUGIN_MAIN_FILE,'clsc_install');
// Create new database fields
function clsc_install() {
    $clsc_options = array(

        'Login_link'        => 'test1',
        'Login_string'      => 'test2',
        'Login_class'       => 'test3',
        'Logout_link'       => 'test4',
        'Logout_string'     => 'test5',
        'Logout_class'      => 'test6',
        'Account_link'      => 'test7',
        'Account_string'    => 'test8',
        'Account_class'     => 'test9'

    );
    add_option('clsc_options', $clsc_options, '', 'yes');
}
```

Comment: Don't matter. I have accepted it! It helped a lot and made perfect sense! Thanks a lot @Meathanjay